# Magento Storefront Missing CSS (Loading from incorrect location)

Tags: ubuntu, magento, magento-installation

I just did a fresh installation of Magento on an Ubuntu server, and when I load the wepbage, all the CSS is missing. When I go to Devtools > Network and check the location its trying to load the CSS from, I get this: <my.ip>/static/**version1657058741**/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/mage/calendar.css

The version folder does not exist on the server. Instead, the CSS is located in /static/frontend/Magento... So why is Magento trying to load CSS from this version folder and how can I instead get it to load directly from /static/frontend?

**Edit**: I've already tried changing the dev_static_sign value to 0 (disabled), but it seemingly had no effect.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try executing following 3 commands and check if issue is fixed

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Answer (score 0):

**For apache**

Make sure according to your version that you have an .htaccess file in pub/ folder.

Some earlier versions have the .htaccess one level back. Try to find the .htaccess from the magento repository for your version if its missing.

You can try to remove the vendor and do a clean composer install again, which brings back the missing .htaccess files upon end.